# Python script / Notepad++ - Ignore case

Tags: python, notepad++

Looking for a way to ignore case on a regex replace with Python script on Notepad++

Tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
editor.rereplace(r'aaaa', r'bbbb', re.IGNORECASE)
```

=> So the replacement should replace any mix of four letters length 'aA' such as :

'AAAA', 
'aaAA', 
'aAaa' 
etc...

to 'bbbb'

Python script version is 1.0.8.0

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me. Npp `7.7.1` 64bit ; python Script `1.3.0.0`

Comment: Thanks, my tools maybe a bit outdated then

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

```
import re
your_editor_text_string = 'I have an OLD_tEXt for this Old_tEXt'
to_be_replaced = re.compile(re.escape('old_text'), re.IGNORECASE)
new_text = to_be_replaced.sub('NEW_TEXT', your_editor_text_string)
print(new_text)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. On which one would you apply the lower() ? I want the searched pattern to be replaced whatever case it is in.

Comment: To the string(s) you want to make the replacements. If all characters are lowercase then they will be replaced for sure.

Comment: The replacements are in Notepad page. I can't apply lower() to the entire page.

Comment: Just add the editor text to a string variable make your replacements and replace the new one back again.

Comment: This will also lowercase letters we don't want to replace `aAaA BCde` --> `aaaa bcde` -> `bbbb bcde`

Comment: Ok now i did understand what exactly you wanted. See the updated solution.